# How to delete the index.php from the end of an URL?

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am building a multi wordpress website from frontend side, where every user has a common but unique own webpage.

For example: John has: https://john.mydomain.com/sponsor/johndoe
Other example: Garfield has: https://garfield.mydomain.com/sponsor/garfieldcat

With help of MrWhite we wrote the following code, what does what is need. Only one problem is left: I should to remove the /index.php from every URL.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.
RewriteRule !^sponsor/ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/sponsor/%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

If i open the URL: https://john.mydomain.com/ i should get https://john.mydomain.com/sponsor/johndoe instead of https://john.mydomain.com/sponsor/johndoe/index.php

Comment: Just from admin side set the permlink it will work automatically

Answer (score 0):

Please check your permalink settings :), **Settings → Permalinks**

https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Permalinks_Screen